# When to change trackbar value when playing video?

Tags: c#, directx

I made application which plays video using DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video class.
There are methods Play(), Pause(), etc...
How should I know when to change value to my trackbar which tracks how much video passed?
Should I create timer and at some interval update my trackbar or there is another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it by a timer indeed. If you have your own samplegrabber callback you get the position provided by a callback (however not always rate aware) and CurrentTime is rate aware. Checking it by a timer also helps you to have the information on the right thread from the start.

Comment: Ok, than I'll check it by a timer. :)

Comment: If you want to make a more customizable solution later on be sure to check out DirectShow.NET it is on sourceforge and very mature (at least from my experience). It is a rather complete wrapper for complete Directhow, and loaded with examples.

Comment: Also, when you use this and the samplegrabber callback (DirectShow.NET). One pitfall here is to rely on the timestamp that the callback provides, don't use this because it is not adjusted to play-rate, in case you use this. But this is probably not your use-case ;-).